# How to delete nested form group from Reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form, something like this:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormGroup({
     test1: new FormControl(''),
     ...
     }),
  });
```

I want to remove the nested formGroup or at least make it empty, something like this:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

I tried `patchValue({})`, `setValue({})` and `this.profileForm.removeControl('address')`.
I got no error but the formgroup is not deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting the `formGroup`? Do you want to hide the displayed form in the template?

Comment: I have a condition,  I need to sent to api the form group, but sometimes I need to send the the formgroup Address and sometimes I need to send it empty or not to send it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `this.profileForm.removeControl('address');` is necessary to use `this.profileForm.updateValueAndValidty();`

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comment:

> I need to sent to api the form group, but sometimes I need to send the the formgroup Address and sometimes I need to send it empty or not to send it at all

I would say that removing part of the from the form group completely, while it should work, might not be the best solution, as it is a destructive operation that will impact the behavior of your form should you want to reuse it after the API call.

A better solution might be to copy the form value and edit it before sending:

```
    const valueToSend = {...this.profileForm.value};
    delete valueToSend['address'];
```

You can see this [working on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvdpys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.ts%3AL65). Switch to "Profile Editor" and see two buttons: "Remove control and send" and "Copy and send", and observe DevTools console.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
profileForm.removeControl('address')
```

i tested this using form group builder

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible ways to get your desired result:

1. Use `profileForm.get('address').reset()`. This will reset the form to default values.
2. Delete the address yourself after getting it with `.value`:

```js
const profile = this.profileForm.value;
delete profile.address;
```